# opencart additional email recipent from contact form

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to edit contact.php file of opencart so that it send email to multiple email id when a contact form is filled.

```
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
```

tried

```
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'),'manager@domain.com','ceo@domain.com');
```

Above edit did not work. How to hard code additional email ids? in such way that reply all works when replied by anyone of recipient from his email box.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source code of the [SMTP adapter](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/0ed2675b2bfb4321c2c2fb929fe90e1fac0555d2/upload/system/library/mail/smtp.php) for Opencart, you can see that the `to` address accepts an array (as follows):

```
if (is_array($this->to)) {
    $to = implode(',', $this->to);
} else {
    $to = $this->to;
}
```

So, you could update your code as follows and pass the addresses in as an array:

```
$mail->setTo(array(
    $this->config->get('config_email'),
   'manager@domain.com',
   'ceo@domain.com'
));
```